# Javascript How to show img and text in child if source HTML text?

Tags: javascript, html, image, text, containers

```
function addTextArea(){
    var textArea = document.createElement("textarea");
    textArea.id="tA";
    textArea.type="textarea";
    textArea.style.position = 'absolute';
    textArea.style.top = 120+count*30;
    textArea.style.left = 40;
    textArea.style.width=2000;
    textArea.style.height=2000;
    textArea.style.fontSize=20;
    textArea.textContent="";
    document.body.appendChild(textArea);
    document.getElementById("stat2").textContent="Numbers of messages " + count;
}

function readText(){
    this.checked=false;
    document.getElementById("tA").innerHTML = this.textContent;

}
```

This is fragment of code. 
obj this.contett is HTML text with img inside and  looks like:

```
Mr. Millepied said that he had decided to focus on his own choreography and to return to Los Angeles, where he still directs the L.A. Dance Project.
<br><br><br>
<a href="http://rc.feedsportal.com/r/247390452602/u/31/f/640350/c/34625/s/4d5be40f/sc/13/rc/1/rc.htm" rel="nofollow">
    <img src="http://rc.feedsportal.com/r/247390452602/u/31/f/640350/c/34625/s/4d5be40f/sc/13/rc/1/rc.img" border="0">
</a>
<br><br>
```

I have inserted space in tags to show this string. 
How can I show all elements of this string. Now I see just the text.

Comment: Where do you call `readText()`? And why do you assign `textContent` to `innerHTML`?

Comment: And what is a `<display>` element? Wouldn't you want `var textArea = document.createElement("textarea");`? Also, `type` wouldn't be a valid attribute on a textarea.

Comment: with a textarea the same result, as with img, display, body etc...

Comment: readText called on mouseclick before
document.getElementById(count).onclick=readText;

this.textContent - container for the text. We dont know what kind of text is it.Maybe simple text, maybe HTML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
// this is the html as a string:
var textContent = '<b>bold</b><img src="https://encrypted-tbn2.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRyabY4muPNtmNIn81wEdmRb9hFlNJuMLLlwX9vvLzucpIpp2Wu"/>';
var count = 1;
function addTextArea(){
    var textArea = document.createElement("textarea");
    textArea.id="tA";
    textArea.type="textarea";
    textArea.style.position = 'absolute';
    textArea.style.top = 120+count*30;
    textArea.style.left = 40;
    textArea.style.width=2000;
    textArea.style.height=2000;
    textArea.style.fontSize=20;
    textArea.textContent="";
    document.body.appendChild(textArea);
    document.getElementById("stat2").textContent="Numbers of messages " + count;
}

function readText(){
    this.checked=false;
    document.getElementById("tA").innerHTML = textContent;

}

addTextArea();
readText();
```

```html
<div id="stat2"></div>
```